# How to include 2 words within Regex and result must be based on only those 2 words VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf

I would like to know how to include only 2 or more keywords within a Regex.  and ending results should only show those words defined, not only one word.

What I currently have works with multiple keywords but I want it to use BOTH words not either one of the other.

For example:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(?i)[\t ](?<w>((arma)|(crapo))[a-z0-9]*)[\t ]"
```

Now the code works fine by including 'arma' or 'crapo'. I only want it to include BOTH 'arma' AND 'crapo' otherwise do not show any results.

Dealing with finding certain keywords within a PDF document and I only want to be shown results if the PDF document includes BOTH 'arma' and 'crapo'      (Works fine by showing results for 'arma' OR 'crapo' I want to see results based on 'arma' AND 'crapo'.

Sorry for sounding so repetitive.

Edit: Here is my code. Please read comment.

```
Dim filesz() As String = GetPatternedFiles("c:\temp\", New String() {"tes*.pdf", "fes*.pdf", "Bas*.pdf"})

'The getpatterenedfiles is a function"  also gettextfromPDF is another function.
    For Each s As String In filesz

        Dim thetext As String = Nothing

        Dim pattern As String = "(?i)[\t ](?<w>(crapo)|(arma)[a-z0-9]*)[\t ]"

        thetext = GetTextFromPDF(s)

            For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(thetext, pattern)

                ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
            Next

    Next
```

Comment: Can you give examples of input and desired output?

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what you mean but, I have couple hundred of PDF files, and I only want the list of PDF files containing those two keyword,  "arma" AND "crapo",  now the code works fine for including 'arma' OR 'crapo'. but I only want results if 1 PDF document includes BOTH 'arma' AND 'crapo".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\barma\b.*?\bcrapo\b|\bcrapo\b.*?\barma\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gO9kF7/1)**

[image]

The idea is to match `arma` whatever `crapo` or `crapo` whatever `arma` and use word boundaries to avoid words like karma.

However, if you want to match karma or crapotos as you asked in your comment you can use:

```
arma.*?crapo|crapo.*?arma
```

Comment: This seems to be the ideal fix, however its my intention to capture words like "karma" and "crapotos" within the PDF.  so if i remove the /b  would that remove the boundaries?

Comment: @TuckingFypo yup, if you want to capture karma or crapotos then remove word boundaries `\b`. I'll update the answer with that

Comment: Fede, so the above fix should work as explained?  ... keep in mind that the code will process one PDF at a time, and it should only give me results if those two word exists within that PDF file.  I do not want it to process if only ONE of the words exist within that PDF file.  Thanks in advance if you confirm that.

Comment: Also,  I want it to ignore if the keywords are either in uppercase  or lowercase.  I will try implementing your code into my above code, since mines works as it should.

Comment: @TuckingFypo just add the key insensitive flag. Check the link http://regex101.com/r/gO9kF7/3. Btw, if your question is answered you might consider marking it as resolved :)

Comment: Fede, please forgive my lack of understanding,  so I think the end result of the code should be.... Dim pattern As String =  "(?i)[\t ](?<w>arma.*?crapo|crapo.*?arma[a-z0-9]*)[\t ]"

Comment: @TuckingFypo I'm not familiar with vb so can't say what is the exact syntax. You could check vb regex documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1. The regex is what I put in my answer `arma.*?crapo|crapo.*?arma ` you only have to figure out how to use the insensitive flag.

Comment: Hello, I've tried all sort of combination and it still doesn't work.  perhaps I don't know the proper way to use your code